How to add pause to image scrolling over video using FFMPEG?
I have a command to scroll image over video using FFMPEG:
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -loop 1 -t 10 -i "image.png" -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=y='t*250'" -qscale 1 output.mp4

What needs to be added to this command so that the image scrolls not immediately, but after 3 seconds?
I need the image to completely cover the video for the first 3 seconds, and then slide down after 3 seconds. The video and image resolution are the same.

Simply use an if condition:
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -loop 1 -t 10 -i image.png -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay=y='if(gte(t,3), (t-3)*250, 0)'" -qscale 1 output.mp4

where:

gte(t,3) means time greater or equal 3 seconds
(t-3) adjusts the movement by 3 seconds
0 is your constant position of the image


Thank you very much! You helped me a lot, your code works great.
